# open text files in one application

Tags: delphi, mutex

I want to write an text editor and to assign the txt files to it. My problem is that I want to have only one instance running and when a new file is opened to send the filename to the first app that is already running... (I want to do this using mutex). Here is a small test

DPR looks like this

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils,
  Forms,
  wndMain in 'wndMain.pas' {frmMain};

{$R *.res}

var
  PrevWindow : HWND;
  S : string;
  CData : TCopyDataStruct;
begin 
  PrevWindow := 0;
  if OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, False, 'MyMutex') <> 0 then
  begin
  repeat
     PrevWindow:=FindWindow('TfrmMain', nil);
  until PrevWindow<>Application.Handle;

     if IsWindow(PrevWindow) then
     begin
        SendMessage(PrevWindow, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
        BringWindowToTop(PrevWindow);
        SetForegroundWindow(PrevWindow);

        if FileExists(ParamStr(1)) then
        begin
           S:=ParamStr(1);
           CData.dwData:=0;
           CData.lpData:=PChar(S);
           CData.cbData:=1+Length(S);

           SendMessage(PrevWindow, WM_COPYDATA, 0, DWORD(@CData) );
           end;
        end;
     end
   else
      CreateMutex(nil, False, 'MyMutex');

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

PAS:

```
type TfrmMain = class(TForm)
   memo: TMemo;
   private
      procedure WMCopyData ( var msg : TWMCopyData ) ; message WM_COPYDATA;
  public
     procedure OpenFile(f : String);
end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.WMCopyData ( var msg : TWMCopyData ) ;
var
   f : String;
begin
   f:=PChar(msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
   //ShowMessage(f);
   OpenFile(f);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.OpenFile(f : String);
begin
   memo.Clear;
   memo.Lines.LoadFromFile(f);
   Caption:=f;
end;
```

this code should be ok, but if i want to open a text file (from the second app), the first app receives a message like this:

[alt text http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/2175/errorjd.jpg](http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/2175/errorjd.jpg)

thanks

Comment: That mutex code is wrong. Always use `CreateMutex`, not `OpenMutex`. Also, that `FindWindow` loop is pointless. That function would only return the current application's window handle if your application's title were "TfrmMain," but why would you ever name your application that? Besides, if `FindWindow` *does* return your application's window handle, repeated calls aren't going to give a different answer, so that loop will either run exactly once, or it will run forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're using Delphi 2009 or Delphi 2010. Those version use Unicode strings, so the `Length` function tells the number of *characters* in a string, but not the number *bytes*. The `wm_CopyData` message needs to know the number of bytes to send. Multiply the character count by two, or `SizeOf(WideChar)`.

```
CData.lpData := PWideChar(S);
CData.cbData := (1+Length(S)) * SizeOf(WideChar);
```

Comment: This will work as long as you don't try to reuse the code in a non-unicode version.  If you do that, it wil break. Better to use `PChar` and `sizeof(char)` and let the compiler take care of the interpretation.

Comment: I'd prefer to make it explicit in this case because we're dealing with interprocess communication. Both sides need to agree regarding the size and format of the payload. If one side is compiled in Unicode mode and the other isn't, my code will fail to compile, hinting that something's wrong, whereas code that uses PChar will compile find on both sides, but the communication will fail at run time.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Unicode problem.  You're probably in D2009  or D2010.   You need to give the size in bytes, not in chaaracters.  Try multiplying your `length` call by `sizeof(char)` and it should work.

Comment: +1 : This is probably going to be the most common mistake of Delphi developers for the years to come. Instead of "SizeOf(Char)", I'd suggest using "StringElementSize(StringVariable)".